# Is there a way to prevent "best common type" resolution from happening in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to prevent the following sort of problems in TypeScript:

```
interface Consumer<a> { consume(value: a): void }
function consumeValue<a>(consumer: Consumer<a>, value: a) {
    consumer.consume(value);
}
var consumer : Consumer<number> = { consume(value) { console.log('Number: ' + value); } }
consumeValue(consumer, 'Hey!'); // <-- this is legit, thank to the best common type resolution that really works!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There currently isn't a good straightforward way to prevent this other than to manually specify the generic type parameters:

```
consumeValue<number>(consumer, 'Hey!');
```

A change to this behavior is [under discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/805) as part of TypeScript adding union types, and as a [separate proposal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/360) for a command-line flag.